# How to change the name of the application without having to rewrite the code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am looking to change the name of the application, but dont want to rewrite the code.

Can anyone help me with this problem....

Thanx in advance

Comment: Do you have any of the source code?  Or are you hoping to pass off someone else's application as your own?

Comment: What do you mean the name of the application ? the title on the mail windows ? the exe name ?

Comment: The name which appears on the iphone below the icon image on the iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the application executable name that your app target compiles.  The simple way to do this is:

1. Expand the "Executables" section
2. Highlight the executable you want to rename
3. Click again to begin editing, and type in the name you want.

Alternatively you can update the bundle display name in info.plist, but this is really just substituting your build product, more on that here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3530-rename-iphone-xcode-projects.html